# Is there a closed form, or cleaner way of writing a function satisfying $\frac{d^nf(x)}{dx^n}|_{x=0}=f(n)$ for all $n$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, closed-form

Given the following, and assuming that $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable:
$$\frac{d^nf(x)}{dx^n}\Bigg|_{x=0}=f(n)$$
What functions $f$ could satisfy this equation? Do any functions of $f$ have a closed form, or if not does it have a form that is just a normal ODE form?

Comment: From what you've written it looks like: $$f(x=n)=f^{(n)}(0)$$ I've written $x=n$ to show that we are primarily defining $f$ in terms of $x$ which applies of the right. However you could also say: $$f(n)=f^{(n)}(0)$$

Comment: @Henry Lee I used the notation I did only because I'm more familiar with it. Is the notation you suggest preferred, or the standard notation?

Comment: They both mean the same thing and what you have showed is equal and shows what you mean

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=a^{x+1}$, where $a$ satisfies $\ln(a)=a$. Then $f^{(n)}(0)=\ln^n(a) a^{1}=a^{n+1}=f(n)$, as desired. Note that $a$ will be a complex number here, explicitly in terms of Lambert’s W: $a=e^{-W(-1)}\approx 0.318+1.337i$.

Comment: Is this exclusively the only answer or are there other functions that satisfy my conditions?

Comment: I can't see how $ln^n(a)a^1=a^{n+1}$...

Comment: @Thehx: look at the definition of $a$.

Comment: oh god, this is beautiful.